# Data mining option not showing in view tab in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-mining

I have installed Oracle 11g on my laptop. I opened SQL Developer and created admin and dmuser for data mine. When I tried to create data miner repository, data miner option is not showing up in the "view" tab. Can anyone identify what the problem is? I re-installed 11g and I have been stuck with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which 11g edition is it?

According to documentation (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/odm/odmrinstallation-2080768.html), you need

- Data Miner
- Oracle Text
- XML DB
- the SH schema

All those options are automatically installed along with the **Enterprise Edition** (otherwise, they are not).

Then there's SQL Developer where you can create Data Miner Repository, but - first check whether all the prerequisites are met.

Comment: my oracle version is 11g r2

Comment: It is Enterprise Edition

Comment: That should be OK, then. Which SQL Developer version do you use?

Comment: That's probably 3.x or 4.x, can't remember any more. How about downloading & installing the latest version (19.2, currently; link is here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: my university recomended me only 11g.That's why I can't install latest version.any way thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not talking about the *database*, but *SQL Developer*; things might have changed between versions so - that's why I thought that the newest version might show things you can't see in lower one(s).